# Intercept group selection in WKInterfaceTable

Tags: swift2, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacetable

I have a group within a WKInterfaceTable and use the function **didSelectRowAtIndex** to intercept the selection of a row and do other stuff. It all works great except for the fact that as soon as the user touches the row I would like to change its backgroundColor and I can't figure out how to achieve this behaviour.

The first lines of the function look like this:

```
override func table(table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int) {

    let slctedRow = self.mainTable.rowControllerAtIndex(rowIndex) as! MainTableRowController
    slctedRow.rowMainGroup.setBackgroundColor(self.rowSelectedColor)
```

Unfortunately the row does not change color immediately because the function is not called immediately but only when the user releases the touch.

Is there a way to immediately intercept the touch (and so change the group's background color)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there aren't way to do that. As they said in a doc:

[**Responding to Taps in Table Rows**](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceTable_class/index.html)

> To respond to taps in a table row, implement your interface
>   controller’s table:didSelectRowAtIndex: method. Use that method to
>   present a different interface controller or to perform any other
>   relevant tasks.

That all. Nothing more.